# Is the iPhone cellular data limit enforced in 3rd party Apps?

Tags: iphone, download

I know nothing about iPhone development, but I am drafting a proposal for other people to do the work of creating an App that interfaces with existing systems and data.

I need to know if the 20MB cellular data download limit present on all apple produced apps is enforced by the SDK for 3rd party apps - i.e. If i develop an app that tried to download a larger file will it fail?

**Context:**

The data file we use is approximately 50MB and many of our customers work on the road and have no access to wifi. If the limit is enforced I need to be enable HTTP Range header support on our server and add this to the requirements for the App so that the file can be downloaded in 20MB chunks.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The 20MB limit is one imposed by the App Store itself. The only restrictions seen in third-party apps are ones that the cellular provider wishes to enforce (which typically just means bandwidth caps or overage fees if you go over a download cap). That said, it may be useful to support HTTP Range anyway, in case the download is interrupted and you wish to resume it.

Answer (score 0):

It is enforced; I did not understand your other points.

Comment: so if i develop an app which tries to download a file >20MB it will fail? edited to clarify

Answer (score 0):

The limit exists for downloading both apps and media files (videos, podcasts, etc.), so I'd imagine it's limited for downloads within each app as well.

Comment: Yes, as i clearly state in the context, but i don't want to if i don't have to.

Comment: OK - I didn't know what HTTP Range Header Support was, but after a quick search, I see that you did state that breaking the file into parts is a possibility.

Comment: Fair enough, i guess it wasn't that clear if you don't know that header's purpose... edited to clarify